# Почему отсутствует InitializeComponent отсутствует у класса UserControl?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Создал такой *UserControl*:

```
<UserControl x:Class="TesterApp.UserControls.Alert"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:TesterApp.V"
         mc:Ignorable="d"
         HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Transparent">

    <Border CornerRadius="5" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="#c7c7c7" Background="White">
         <TextBlock Text="rtye" FontSize="16" Padding="10"></TextBlock>        
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

Автоматом мне создало вот это `xaml.cs`:

```
namespace TesterApp.V
{
    public partial class AlertControl : UserControl
    {
        public AlertControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Но IS ругается следующим:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему так?

Comment: Вы перемещали, переименовывали, что-то еще делали с файлами?

Comment: `x:Class="TesterApp.UserControls.Alert"` и `namespace TesterApp.V`

Comment: @АндрейNOP, вроде нет. Но если дело в этом, можно попробовать его удалить и создать снова.

Comment: Ага, у вас отличается полное название класса в XAML (TesterApp.UserControls.Alert) и в cs (TesterApp.V.AlertControl)

Comment: Приведите XAML в соответствие с cs и принудительно пересоберите проект

Comment: Это не "класс и view'шка", это целый объект - UserControl, который и должен быть целым, лежа в одном месте. Если смотреть по MVVM, то это все является View слоем. Как привязать - создавайте DependencyProperty и привязывайте как обычный контрол (`<myControl myProperty = "{Binding Property}">`).